# How to generate a curve using matlab simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

How to generate the curve of transfer function:

`G0(s)=exp(-s)*[(2s+4)/(s^3+5s^2+6s+4)]`

using MATLAB and Simulink?

Comment: `G = tf( [2 4], [1 5 6 4], 'InputDelay', 1 );`, and then `bode(G);`

Answer (score 1):

What kind of curve do you mean? Bode plot? Nyquist plot? Step response?

Use the [`tf`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/control/ref/tf.html) function to create your transfer function with the `InputDelay` parameter to represent the `exp(-s)`, see [Models with Time Delays](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/control/ug/models-with-time-delays.html) in the documentation for more details.

Once you have your transfer function, you can use functions like [`bode`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/control/ref/bode.html), [`nyquist`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/control/ref/nyquist.html), [`step`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/control/ref/step.html), [`impulse`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/control/ref/impulse.html), etc... to generate your "curve" of choice.

All of this requires the [Control System Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/control/).

Comment: Thank you very much!I want a step response curve.Then approximate the process by the first order plus time delay model using the following methods: two point method,log method,area method,least square method and relay feedback method.Now I cannot even generate a step response!

Comment: Do what I suggested in the answer and you should be able to get a step response (using the `step` function).

Comment: thanks very much,i know how to generate the response curce already.